# How do I set up mockito with IntelliJ idea for java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mockito

I am brand new to java and the IntelliJ IDE.
I have been looking on the internet for hours on how to simply resolve this issue I have been having with IntelliJ and mockito:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

where the mockito part is read and the IDE says it cannot resolve symbol mockito.

I have no idea how the IDE resolves dependencies.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: Do you have a file called `pom.xml` at the root of your project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: No I do not have a file called pom.xml at the root of my project

Comment: Ok, then you have to import the Mockito library manually like explained in RC's comment.

Comment: I have been to that stack overflow question before. I don't see a plus for mockito? Do I have to install it somehow?

Comment: There's a step by step tutorial **with pictures** in the linked question, so [download mockito jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mockito%7Cmockito-core%7C2.8.47%7C) and follow the steps

Comment: Aren't those pictures for Junit? Not Mockito?

Comment: @JonathonHill it is a generic tutorial which explain how to include external jars. You will follow the same steps to include Mockito's jar.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Next error is to do with my classPath I think -> ClassNotFoundException: org.objenesis.ObjenesisStd

Comment: Mockito uses Objenesis. Hence, you also need to import the jar for Objenesis in your classpath. Adding transitive jars can be painful. Maven is intended to manage them automatically. You might give it a try.